# pyqgis 3.4.4 - Segmentation fault error

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I try to run a simple code in pyqgis with no gui and I get a segmentation fault error by only invoking QGSApplication.

The code is the following one (under Ubuntu16.04 and with python 3.5)

```py
from qgis.core import *

# supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(QgsApplication.prefixPath(), True)

# create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
# second argument to False disables the GUI
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

qgs.exitQgis()
```

In order to reproduce the error, I made a simple Github repository (https://github.com/mbrasebin/test_pyqgis_crash) with [the code](https://github.com/mbrasebin/test_pyqgis_crash/blob/master/test.py) and [a Travis configuration file](https://github.com/mbrasebin/test_pyqgis_crash/blob/master/.travis.yml) (to set the environnement). 
The log error can be viewed on [travis pages](https://travis-ci.org/mbrasebin/test_pyqgis_crash).

If you have an idea to correct the error (or at least to catch it) do not hesitate to answer and/or to fork the repository.

Mickaël

------------------- EDIT

By launching the script with gdb, the error seems to be related to a QT class used through qgis. If you have an idea to avoid or catch this error ...

```
Thread 1 "python3" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffeaf23261 in QSqlDatabase::close() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Sql.so.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code works by turning it into :

```
from qgis.core import *

def run():
    # supply path to qgis install location
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True)

    # create a reference to the QgsApplication, setting the
    # second argument to False disables the GUI
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

    # load providers
    qgs.initQgis()


    print("I ran")

    qgs.exitQgis()

run()
```

[The test now passes](https://travis-ci.org/mbrasebin/test_pyqgis_crash). It is quite magic.

Comment: I just come across this myself. Have you found an idea or logic behind why this actually works?