# pyqgis 2.18.16 - Segmentation fault error at 2nd run

Tags: pyqgis, linux, memory

When use pyqgis+python for auto-mapping, I encounter a tricky `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error, at the 2nd run of the program. I checked previous similar [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310110/pyqgis-3-4-4-segmentation-fault-error) but not able to fix the issue.

I have a simple function: `test_qgis.py`, with content:

```
def test_QGIS_init():
    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeAllMapLayers()
    ##do the processing, cropping polygon, produce map, etc.
    ##app.exitQgis()
```

and then test with a test file "test.py" in the same folder:

```
import test_qgis
print '-------------------test qgis start -------------'
test_qgis.test_QGIS_init()
print '-------------------test qgis 2nd round -------------'
test_qgis.test_QGIS_init()
exit(0)
```

The output will be fine for the 1st run, but failed at the 2nd time.

```
-------------------test qgis start -------------
-------------------test qgis 2nd round -------------
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any clue?

It it also interesting that, 1) turn on the `exitQgis()` at the end of the function does not help; 2)if I run the test through X server remotely, then the test passes without the `Segmentation fault` error.

I would try to keep this version of `pyqgis` as some function I have tested only working on this version.

---

Here is my system information:
**OS version**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

**python**

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Aug 22 2019, 16:36:40)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
```

***QGIS***

```
>>> from qgis.core import QGis
>>> QGis.QGIS_VERSION
u'2.18.16'
>>> QGis.QGIS_RELEASE_NAME
u'Las Palmas'
```

Comment: If I turn `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath('/usr', **True**)`  to **False**, then the 1st run will also fail at: 
```...    ms=QgsMapSettings(); ....  
composition= QgsComposition(ms);  ... 
document = QtXml.QDomDocument();  ... ```
**`composition.loadFromTemplate(document)`**
error message: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.  This [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216371/qgscomposition-loadfromtemplate-method-causing-segmentation-fault) mentioned similar error, but no clear solution.